# Responsive web design, how does it work?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, meta-tags

I am trying to make a webpage that changes the way it looks depending on what device you are using.

I think media queries and viewport is the thing I need to use.

Can someone confirm this and also tell me how i should go about making a webpage that uses this functionality?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google **css media queries tutorial**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about this:

1. you can use user agent testing ( this is when you use something lime modernizer or php to test the user agent. You would then use PHP if statements or something like it to load different content for different devices
2. you could use the same content for every device and just change the way it looks using CSS media queries ( this is what i use ) you can see it in action in app i've build called LeadRocket app.myleadrocket.com make an account and scale your screen size down

cheers

P.S. this is a great boiler plate for media queries it's what i used to build www.myleadrocket.com

http://www.getskeleton.com/

Answer (score 0):

Haha, this would take a while to answer. The essentials are as follows....

Paste this into the `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

That meta tag will allow you to use media queries. Then at the end of your main css file use media queries like the following to make any changes based on screen width.

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
  /* Everything in here will be styled for small desktops */
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* Everything in here will be styled for tablets */
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  /* Everything in here will be styled for mobile */
}
```

The styles in the media queries will overwrite any style rules used previously in your stylesheet.

Comment: Here is the meta tag... <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: how will each of the @media lines make it style for desktops etc they all say 979px??

Comment: The second one should be 767px and the third 480px... not sure what I did there. The media queries can be any width that works with your design and you can have as many as you want. Just experiment a bit and you will get the hang of it.